# Injecting dependencies in a Android ViewModel?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

Hi i have a ViewModel that has two var's that get injected using Dagger 2.11.

However it never gets injected in my viewModel whilst everywhere else in my app, these same dependecy Vars get initialised and injected perfectly

Below is my viewModel

```
class MyViewModel : AndroidViewModel, MyViewModelContract {


    private lateinit var pointsBalance: MutableLiveData<PointsBalance>


    @Inject
    lateinit var accountDelegator: AccountDelegatorContract



@Inject
constructor(application: Application) : super(application)

init {
    DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().application(getApplication() as MyApplication).build().inject(this)
}

    override fun getPointsBalance(): LiveData<PointsBalance> {
        if (!this::pointsBalance.isInitialized) {
           //get balance from network api etc
        }

        return pointsBalance
    }
```

accountDelegator complains that it is not initialised

Below is how i bind this viewModel inside MyModule.class

```
   @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    fun providesViewModel(viewModel: MyViewModel): MyViewModelContract = viewModel
```

my custom application

```
class MyApplication : DaggerApplication() {
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        val applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
        applicationComponent.inject(this)
        return applicationComponent
    }

}
```

my applicationComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(MyModule::class,
        ))
interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {
    fun inject(mApplication: MyApplication)
    override fun inject(instance: DaggerApplication)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(applicaton: MyApplication): Builder
        fun build(): ApplicationComponent
    }


}
```

How i use this viewmodel in a activity/fragment

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe issue is that you're not calling `inject`.  You'd need for a start to add following to `ApplicationComponent`

```
void inject(MyViewModel viewModel);
```

What I'm doing here then fwiw is inheriting from `AndroidViewModel` (which gives access to application instance) then calling following in ViewModel class (you'd need to substitute `DaggerProvider.getComponent` with however you're accessing component in your code)

```
init {
    DaggerProvider.getComponent(application).inject(this)
}
```

Comment: I now get this error: 

Cannot create an instance of class MyViewModel

Comment: Ok nevermind i have fixed that error, however i still get the issue on the dependency var not being injected

Comment: @jonney what do you have in your `init`?

Comment: I have updated my answer to describe what i added to the constructor and init

Comment: hmm, not sure in that case what the issue is.  fwiw on another project I'm using a different approach again (using `ViewModelProvider.Factory` instance that's injected in to Activity/Fragment) that perhaps might be useful - https://github.com/joreilly/galway-bus-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/surrus/galwaybus/ui/viewmodel

Comment: None of those viewModels from the link provided have any dependency injected fields. The issue i am having is that my dependency injected fields are null and not getting injected. Elsewhere in the app they are fine

Comment: @jonney they're injected through constructor as part of `ViewModelProvider.Factory` dagger config which then creates the `ViewModel` (and provides the inject params)

Comment: That approach has advantage of removing android framework dependencies from 'ViewModel` code